# Configure Firewall for Remote Debugging Dialog pops up for local database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Starting a few days ago, the dialog to configure remote debugging pops up even when I try to debug on a local database. This has never happened before for my local machine. It opens whenever I try to debug a local script or stored procdure. On some scripts I can click X on the dialog and the local debug continues. But on some other more complicated scripts, it won't debug all all?

Do I have to configure the debugger as specified? If I select a choice in the dialog to unblock remote debugging, I get an error message that says the port cannot be added and to add it manually to the firewall.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is generally required when you are connecting from a different computer rather than where the database engine exists.
But I have observed that the problem also can occur if you are specifying computer name or ip address instead of specifying loop back address (127.0.0.1) or (local) as server name even though the database engine is on local machine. In such case, the debugger needs to be configured.
Details of how to configure are [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646024%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)